# Create a new pandas column with repeating a value according with another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table like this

```
    times  v2  
0    4     10  
1    2     20  
2    0     30/n30  
3    1     40  
4    0     9
```

What I want if change the values of v2 when times != 0, and the change consists in adding "\0" as many times as the times columns says.

```
    times  v2  
0    4     10\n0\n0\n0\n0  
1    2     20\n0\n0  
2    0     30\n30  
3    1     40\n0  
4    0     9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df.v2+=df.times.map(lambda x : x*"\n0")
df
Out[325]: 
   times              v2
0      4  10\n0\n0\n0\n0
1      2        20\n0\n0
2      0          30/n30
3      1           40\n0
4      0               9
```